# Manage checkout form validation (required fields) with ajax

Tags: magento2, frontend, ajax, form-validation, checkout-page

How can I manage checkout page required fields programmatically. I want to Add or remove required fields with ajax based on customer selected parameter (country, shipping method...)? I have read the Magento 2 official doc-s but have not found anything useful in them.